# Обращение к элементу массива, в котором записана строка (Си)

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Добрый день!

Как можно, при вводе строки с клавиатуры с помощью fgets, обратиться к элементу введённой строки?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
      char str[10];
      fgets(str,NULL,stdin);// вводим Hello
      printf("%c\n",str[2]);// получаем e
      return(0); 
}
```

P.S: желательно без string.h

Comment: тип char имеет модификатор доступа для printf **%c** а не **%s**! Вот и вся ошибка. А обращаетесь правильно `str[2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас неправильно записан вызов `fgets`.

Вместо

```
  fgets(str,NULL,stdin);// вводим Hello
            ^^^^
```

должно быть

```
  fgets(str, sizeof( str ), stdin);// вводим Hello
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Для вывода одного символа просто укажите символ форматирования `%c`

```
  printf("%c\n",str[2]);
```

Выражение `str[2]` имеет тип `char`, в то время как символ форматирования `%s`используется для вывода строк и ожидает на входе указатель типа `char *`.

Если вы хотите вывести строку, начиная с некоторого символа, то можете записать

```
  printf("%s\n",&str[2]);
```

или

```
  printf("%s\n",str + 2);
```

Имейте в виду, что str[2] соответствует символу `l` в строке `Hello`, так как индексация начинается с 0.

Comment: ошибку уже не выдаёт, но символ всё равно не выводит

Comment: @Arden Смотрите мой дополненный ответ.

Comment: Да, точно, fgets(str, sizeof( str ), stdin), глупая ошибка. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Однако, мне всё ещё нужен один единственный символ.

Comment: @Arden Я показал, как вывести на консоль один символ.

Comment: думаю, @Arden хочет пример вида `char c = str[2]; printf("%c\n",c);`

Comment: @Arden А что меняется, если ввести промежуточную переменную c?

Comment: понимание @Arden.

Comment: @KoVadim Кому? Я думаю, что если автор использует str[2], то это уже говорит о его понимании, что он делает:)

Comment: я бы не был столь уверенным.

Comment: Всё в порядке, я разобрался :)

Comment: @Arden Это радует.:)